# How to read data from a web url and echo only a part (unique) to the page?

Tags: php

For a project that bans abusers(malware downloaders) of networks automatically.
We need to get a  unique list of IP's so our software can automatically block it at the gate before it can do any kind of  damage.

Situation is the following:

We have data at an URL like the following:  (Example: https://urlhaus.abuse.ch/feeds/asn/14061/)

Webdata:

```
# Dateadded (UTC),URL,URL_status,Threat,Tags,Host,IPaddress,number,Country
"2019-08-01 05:05:02","http://185.240.25.99/sparc","offline","malware_download","gafgyt|exploit|elf","185.240.25.99","185.204.25.99","14258","NL"
"2019-08-01 05:04:03","http://185.240.25.99/sh4","offline","malware_download","gafgyt|elf","185.240.25.99","185.240.25.99","14258","NL"
"2019-08-01 05:03:04","http://185.240.25.99/i686","offline","malware_download","elf|gafgyt|exploit","185.240.25.99","185.240.25.99","14258","NL"
"2019-08-01 05:03:02","http://185.240.25.99/mips","offline","malware_download","gafgyt|elf","185.240.25.99","185.240.25.99","14258","NL"
"2019-08-01 05:02:03","http://185.240.25.99/i586","offline","malware_download","gafgyt|elf","185.240.25.99","185.240.25.99","14258","NL"
"2019-07-31 14:06:10","http://185.240.25.115/dll/driver_update_service.sh4","online","malware_download","mirai|elf","185.240.25.115","185.240.25.115","14258","NL"
"2019-07-31 14:06:08","http://185.240.25.115/dll/driver_update_service.m68k","online","malware_download","mirai|elf","185.240.25.115","185.240.25.115","14258","NL"
"2019-07-31 14:06:06","http://185.240.25.115/dll/driver_update_service.ppc","online","malware_download","elf","185.240.25.115","185.240.25.115","14258","NL"
```

What i want is to return unique lines for the IP part.
The page should echo only the following unique ips like so:

> 185.240.25.99
>   185.240.25.115

Comment: Webdata has which format? Means array, object?

Comment: @shivaniPatel
I'm not exactly sure but it looks like plain text:
Here is the data URL: https://urlhaus.abuse.ch/feeds/asn/14061/

Comment: @tim i did look there but unfortunately PHP is not my strongest point i would rather do it in  bash then in  PHP but for this project i need this as PHP.
So help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @tim Like i said in my comment i need this data generated by PHP.
As a webserver is handling it before any server that allows bash scripts to be run.

Comment: @tim i will quote what i said " i would rather do it in bash then in PHP but for this project i need this as PHP. So help is greatly appreciated."

Answer (score 1):

Your file is `CSV file`(comma separated). There needs to skip first 11 lines which can be considered as a header. So I have started scanning it from row number 12.

Try to check below:

```
    $row = 1;
    $result = [];
    if (($handle = fopen("https://urlhaus.abuse.ch/feeds/asn/14061/", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        if($row < 12){ $row++; continue; }
        $row++;
        if ( !empty($data[5]) &&  !empty($data[6]))
        {
            if (!empty($data[5])) 
                array_push($result, $data[5]);
            if (!empty($data[6])) 
                 array_push($result, $data[6]);
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    $test = (array_unique(array_values($result)));
    foreach ($test as $key => $val) {
       echo $val."<br>";

    fclose($handle);
    }
```

Comment: Thats almost what i wanted but unfortnally it echo's duplicate IP's
Example: https://www.angelosreef.nl/test.php

Comment: @AngeloKreikamp Please check it now.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I really appreciate it.

check: https://www.angelosreef.nl/test.php
It still prints duplicates and now also an added content:
Array ( [0] => 167.71.172.63 ) It only must return unique ips
Like so: 

159.65.49.210

Comment: Please check it now

Comment: @AngeloKreikamp have you got a chance to check your answer?

Comment: Okay i checked it i did a little edit by doing this
    $test = (array_unique(array_values($result)));
foreach ($test as $key => $val) {
   echo $val."<br>";

I found one problem the array is showing ips where the rows have the status "offline"
It only needs to return the data where the status is "online"

Comment: Okay. Accept the answer if you get the proper solution from it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197380/discussion-between-angelo-kreikamp-and-shivani-patel).